# Calling property of all instances in class by an index number in C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, is it possible to create multiple objects from a class and refer to each instance by an index number?

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
public class movie
{

    public string name;

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        movie[] myMovie = new movie[3];

        myMovie[0].name = "Harry Potter";
        myMovie[1].name = "Lord of The Rings";
        myMovie[2].name = "Star Wars";

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(myMovie[i].name);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's possible and you already did it. What's the question?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: The OP hasn't currently created any `movie` instances. Their code will fail with a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there.

When you do `movie[] myMovie = new movie[3]`, you're correctly creating an array of 3 `movie` elements, but each of those elements will be `null` by default. This means you'll get a `NullReferenceException` if you try and do e.g. `myMovie[0].name = "..."`.

You need to instantiate three separate `movie` instances, and assign them to the appropriate elements in your array. You could do this by hand:

```
movie[] myMovie = new movie[3];
myMovie[0] = new movie();
myMovie[1] = new movie();
myMovie[2] = new movie();
```

However, a `for` loop is a much easier way to do this:

```
movie[] myMovie = new movie[3];
for (int i = 0; i < movie.Length; i++)
{
    myMovie[i] = new movie();
}
```

Alternatively, you could instantiate your `movie` instances, give them their names, and add them to your array in one go like this:

```
movie[] myMovie = new movie[]
{
    new movie()
    {
        name = "Harry Potter",
    },
    new movie()
    {
        name = "Lord of the Rings",
    },
    new movie()
    {
        name = "Star Wars",
    }
};
```

This uses the syntax for [object initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers) and [array initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can have a *collection* of instances; in your case it can be `List<movie>`:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      // Collection of movies (empty) 
      List<movie> myMovie = new List<movie>();

      // Let's add some movies into the collection
      myMovie.Add(new movie() {name = "Harry Potter"});
      myMovie.Add(new movie() {name = "Lord of The Rings"});
      myMovie.Add(new movie() {name = "Star Wars"});

      // Time to inspect the collection 
      Console.WriteLine($"We have {myMovie.Count} movies in the collection");
      Console.WriteLine("They are:"); 

      // myMovie[i] returns i-th movie within the collection 
      for (int i = 0; i < myMovie.Count; ++i)  
        Console.WriteLine($"  {i + 1}. {myMovie[i].name}");
  }
```

Comment: I got the List of objects working. Thank you very much!